# Why it is necessary to use choke for starting bike?

Tags: motorcycle, choke

I purchased Honda CB Shine 125 cc, When I start directly it not start, when I used choke and start bike it start and I on the choke for 10 to 15 secs(The choke case is always happen in morning time in a day). After a year still this process is running. Few times choke I didn't used, but every day I have to used it. Is it compulsory for bike to start it first time with choke?

And What is the benefit of using choke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this used to happen with me too. In the morning the motor is very cold and needs more fuel for burning. Thus without choke the normal mixture of air and fuel goes inside the engine, which it is unable to burn.

Pulling the choke increases the fuel amount in the mixture which burns instantly in the engine thus giving the required thrust to bike. It should not be required on summers at all as the environment is warm and engine is hotter than usual and fuel burns instantly. But in winters it is necessary since whole body including the pistons are very cold.

If this issue happens in summers also or even after bike was running from long time. then I will suggest to take it to service center.

Benefits of using choke -

- Motorcycle runs richer due to more fuel in mixture.
- More power while driving with choke pulled as more fuel burns lowering the mileage.
- No misfires in ignition as the fuel air ratio has more fuel content which fires up easily, without the need of multiple fires.

Disadvantages

- Less mileage as more fuel is consumed
- less life of fuel filter due to excessive fuel passing through them.

Answer (score 3):

When the motor is cold, it needs a higher ratio of fuel to air in the cylinders in order to get them to fire, i.e. you need to add "extra" fuel in order to get it to start. Once warm, however, the engine doesn't need such a rich fuel mixture.

By activating the [choke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_valve), you allow proportionally more fuel into the engine than usual, which lets the motor start; This is normal and the proper way of starting it.